# Why SSgompertz does not work on similar data sets?

Tags: r, nls, logistic-curve

I have data that follows a sigmodial shape and the Gompertz function seem to make sense. I wanted to use SSgompertz in nls to find the parameters, but I get sometimes errors. So, I wanted to learn more about and went through the help documentation (?SSgompertz) but run into a problem:

I subset the data just as in the example
DNase.1 <- subset(DNase, Run == 1)

I plotted the data to verify it has "sigmoidal" shape-ish:

```
plot(log(DNase.1$conc),DNase.1$density)
```

and run nls and SSgompertz:

```
nls(density ~ SSgompertz(log(conc),Asym ,b2,b3),
data = DNase.1)
```

This works, and returns the parameters of an equation of the form:

```
y<-4.6033*exp(-2.2713*0.7165^x)
```

Now, if I save the same data in another object:

```
x<- log(DNase.1$conc)
probando<-data.frame(x=x,y=y)
```

And plot it to be sure it returns the same behavior as in the orignial dataset (which it does):

```
plot(probando$x,probando$y)
```

But, if I want to re-run the same model I got an error:

```
nls(y ~ SSgompertz(x,Asym ,b2,b3),
data = probando)
```

Why is that so?

Comment: You must have left something out as in one model you predict density, in the other y.

Comment: Hi, "y" and "density" are basically the same values. "y" was obtained by using the parameters (asym, b2, b3) after fitting density ~ log(conc). That´s why I found confusing how using almost identical dataset in one case it does not work.